# import kafka is giving "NameError: name 'true' is not defined"

Tags: python, apache-kafka, nameerror

I am trying to use kafka-python to stream csv data but while importing kafka, I'm getting below error. The funny thing is it was working last night and since morning its giving this error all of sudden.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c237685c7217> in <module>
----> 1 import kafka

~/TweetStream/kafka.py in <module>
     29    "id": "interior-tolerance",
     30    "metadata": {
---> 31     "scrolled": true
     32    },`enter code here`
     33    "outputs": [

NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Comment: Is `~/TweetStream/` the folder where you installed Kafka? Or is it the folder where you are writing you code? If you have a `kafka.py` in your own code, then `import kafka` will try to import that instead. Either way, `true` isn't the name Python uses for the boolean true value; Python uses `True` with a capital T. This is part of the fundamentals of Python that you should study and know without prompting, before trying to use sophisticated third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have a file named `kafka` (or perhaps a class or def) that could be overriding the default `kafka-python` module? If so, I would change its name or -- well, just change the name or put it in a subdirectory, as it'll get quite confusing and error-prone otherwise.

It seems in **your** file you have a `true` on line 31 where it should be the python builtin `True` instead.

```
~/TweetStream/kafka.py in <module>

---> 31     "scrolled": true
```

Comment: Oh yes..You are so correct, I had a file named kafka.py inside my working directory. Thank You so much for the quick resolution.